# What does"...pays to get colicky animals." mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From *Ahmad Shah, "[Four Years in Tibet](https://books.google.com/books?id=zC8PAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22no+doubt+pays+to+get+colicky+animals%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGuPrrgqfRAhXKxVQKHc1SDmIQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22no%20doubt%20pays%20to%20get%20colicky%20animals%22&f=false)" (1906)*:

> The crude beginnings of certain sort of veterinary knowledge are also there. Cattle are dosed in the nose; in the case of horses and bulls, the medicine is inserted in the right nostril;... The cure for colic is hard and swift riding, *so that it no doubt pays to get colicky animals*.

It looks like a kind of homeopathic treatment is in play here, but how does one  put it in plain language that would make sense and the reader can understand the outcome of such a treatment?

Comment: I don't think it implies money nor professionally trained veterinarians here. The writer was taking about how people treating their sick animals, in what way. It is more like because the animal suffers from  abdomen pain (colic), the owner takes it for a hard and fast ride, in turn, the ride causes more pain to the poor animal, and thus cure the pain, according to homeopathic principles.

Comment: @Hank This seems unlikely to me. The text says "hard and swift riding", not effective and fast-acting. There's nothing about the differential costs of treatment. I think it's more likely that it pays to buy colicky animals because you can work them harder.

Comment: Y'all are right, I completely misread that.

Comment: @Janef There's nothing about homeopathy in the passage. The principle of that pseudoscience is that like cures like when in dilution sufficient to remove physical presence. The pain from bloating isn't the cause of colic; it's a symptom.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the author is making a joke at the expense of the local vets: if you buy colicky animals, and then ride them hard and fast, they will be cured, and so become more valuable. I do not think this method of profitable horsedealing would be endorsed in the West.

Answer (score 0):

It is 'hard and swift' work curing colic in animals.

First of all, there are certain days which are considered inauspicious for performing these cures. This makes animal-owners keen to employ a fast-acting doctor, rather than travelling too far with their colicky animals. These particular vets are travellers, so can conveniently cure on the go. Not to mention 'veterinary knowledge' is still at it's 'crude beginnings', implying that it is not yet a widely practiced profession, nor very well understood. Certainly an owner would be willing to pay extra for the cure of his colicky animal if it comes his way. The following paragraph in this book immediately goes on to discuss fees, and how it seems insignificant in English money what these travellers earn.

I would deduce from the context above that 'it pays to get colicky animals' is a reference to financial benefit for these travelling medics.

'Hard and swift riding' might also be a euphemism in keeping with terms such as 'crude beginnings' and 'inserted into'. I believe the author is a Christian missionary and medical doctor by profession, and in the very early 20th century, it isn't uncommon to find a book about the 'barbarous Orient'. Someone on Goodreads does in fact review it as 'condescending'!

[image]

Comment: What do you think those phrases are euphemisms for?

Comment: Sexual euphemisms in the vain of what TimLymington is suggesting - 'making a joke at the expense of local vets'. Especially coupled with the concept of veterinarianism still at its 'crude beginnings'; inauspicious days for giving treatment; and the comparison made to 'old time hawkers'. It seems to me that the author finds these travelling vets outdated and backwards, so sexual innuendos play nicely into that mocking/condescending undertone of these vets and their primal practices.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you detect a potential sexual reference in 'The medicine is inserted in the right nostril'?

Comment: I'm saying I note a hint of mockery in pointing out medicine is inserted into the right (as opposed to the left) nostril. Why should it matter? Yet it does in this cultural context which is evidently different to the author's.

Comment: And yes, I'm also saying that the language has sexual (even bestial) undertones in keeping with the image of 'hard and swift riding' as the cure for a colicky horse. Again, not uncommon for western writers to demean the 'other' in this way at this time of writing. If he simply wanted to say 'treating colicky animals is hard work, which needs to be done quickly in order to keep within an auspicious time frame' - he wouldn't have gone out his way to be so creatively equivocal.

Comment: But 'the cure... is hard and swift riding' does not mean 'treating colicky animals is hard work, which needs to be done quickly in order to keep within an auspicious timeframe' or that 'its is hard and swift work [for the vet] curing colic'. It means the animals need to be ridden and made to go fast. The fact that modern web-pages still abound in advice NOT to do this suggest that the beneficiality of hard and fast riding still persists at an instinctive or 'folk wisdom' level.

Comment: Surely what modern websites say and whether literally riding animals persists as a cure for colic (even in 'folk wisdom') or not, is irrelevant to the experiences of a Christian missionary's travels in Tibet in the late 19th century. I have to go by literary context and historical data when arriving at such a conclusion. Do you have a source which suggests that Tibetan travelling medics in the late 1800's rode animals hard and fast in order to cure colic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51180/discussion-between-spagirl-and-littletee).

Comment: @Littletee FYI, the writer wasn't a Christian missionary, but yes, you're right that he was a doctor – worked for the British Colonial Government. However; you're not correct in your assertion and interpretation.This chapter is about medical practice on that particular land by the Tibetans – not inTibet to be precise – but in Ladakh. It isn’t just how sick animals being treated, but people too. That particular paragraph which I have had the question concerning "colicky animals" is the only paragraph on veterinary which has no relation to its preceding nor succeeding paragraph.

Comment: I’m a translator for this book, it isn’t my job nor can I impose my ethic to use my modern-day perspective to judge the author’s intent. My job is to interpret the actual meaning of the writer’s words based on what he had written. You are a reader, and sure you are free to interpret however you wish with your modern-day views, but this does not help answering my question.

Comment: Janef, that's fine. I offered my two cents based on what I could find of this context, and of course you are free to leave it.

Comment: Also, see the following for a reference of his being a Christian missionary. You'll find other sources also refer to Shah with Rev. as a prefix. Why would I make that up? https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PF_-_q5VckcC&pg=PT130&lpg=PT130&dq=Ahmad+shah+Christian+missionary&source=bl&ots=KDeZei-UMs&sig=oD0Xlpm8vwibi2KVlL0RpN63elA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZh-T3k6nRAhWG2BoKHYF0BA0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=Ahmad%20shah%20Christian%20missionary&f=true

Comment: I didn't say you made something up. I'm well aware of his other book that the link you provided. Maybe he changed his career later to a reverend this I don't know and didn't do a research on it. What I pointed out that you were wrong, is in reference to  the book that I've been translating, was written in a period when he was a doctor in Leh. He's later career serving God is of no concern here in regards to this very book.

Comment: @Janef U literally just said 'FYI the writer wasn't a Christian missionary', implying that I made it up. And the link states clearly that the Rev. was searching for Christian manuscripts in Tibet which he documents in 'Four years', no 'other book'. Also, if u follow a source in above link ('The Fifth Gospel' by Dr Hassnain), u'll find a chapter called 'The Tibetan Gospel'. It says Shah was commissioned by the Church to refute claims of a fifth gospel discovered in the region. He went in as an undercover 'hakim' (doctor/wise man) according to Hassnain. Challenges his medical authority if true.

Comment: You would also benefit from reading the chapter on 'Travel Albums and Revisioning Narratives' in "Photography's Orientalism: New Essays on Colonial Representation" as my argument isn't dissimilar (i.e. colonial representational fallacies). Note where the author says: "The eighteenth Kushak Bakula's spiritual powers [...] were mentioned by some westerners who met and left accounts of him. Those by missionaries are anxious and cynical if not spiteful", p.175. In particular, please see footnote #10 where Rev. Ahmad Shah is cited as being 'more favourable' than others, but cynical nonetheless.

Comment: @Littletee,I am very glad that my question on English meaning has opening up for you a new world of the past – with google search at your command. I encourage you don't just read footnotes, but dive into the whole Asiatic Studies which isn't just fascinating but rewarding.

Comment: @Janef Haha thanks, it was enjoyable despite your patronising tone :)